# how to create tar file in date wise folder linux

Tags: linux, command-line, cron

i am using that command to create backup of users images ( via cron job command  )

```
tar -cvf /home/abc/BackupNow/user_$(date +"\%Y.\%m.\%d.\%S.\%N").tar /home/abc/public_html/app/webroot/data/user/ 2> /home/abc/BackupNow/user.log
```

but here  " `/home/abc/BackupNow/user_$(date +"\%Y.\%m.\%d.\%S.\%N").tar` " i want to add date wise folder into backupnow/ folder

like that

```
/home/abc/BackupNow/ $(date) /user_$(date +"\%Y.\%m.\%d.\%S.\%N").tar
```

but its not working. so how to create dynamic folder then put tar file into

### updated

Working >  `tar -cvf "/opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/app/con_$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%S.%N").tar" /opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/app/Controller/`

not working >  `tar -cvf "/opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/app/$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")/con_$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%S.%N").tar" /opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/app/Controller/`

error message >

```
tar: /opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/app/2014_07_09/con_2014.07.09.54.168668034.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably not working because there are spaces in the date. So, to get around that, you will need to put the path inside double quotes:

```
tar -cvf "....path with spaces...."
```

then replace the double quotes in your `date` command with single ones like this:

```
tar -cvf ".... $(date +'...') ..."
```

You may need to create the directory first:

```
DIRECTORY="/home/abc/BackupNow/$(date)"
mkdir -p "$DIRECTORY"
tar -cvf "$DIRECTORY/user_$(date +'\%Y.\%m.\%d.\%S.\%N').tar" ....
```

Comment: Working >  tar -cvf "/opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/app/con_$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%S.%N").tar" /opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/app/Controller/^C


not working >  tar -cvf "/opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/app/$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")/con_$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%S.%N").tar" /opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/app/Controller/

error message > tar: /opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/app/2014_07_09/con_2014.07.09.54.168668034.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: please read updated section . in comment its not well formated

Comment: You need to create the directory first - see my edit.

Comment: actually i am using that command in cron job (cpanel) not in SH file. for that i need to use SH file.